# Gedit from terminal - inconsistent behaviour

Tags: command-line, gedit

I tend to frequently open a text file from the terminal with a command like so:

```
gedit filename.txt
```

However, the behaviour is inconsistent; sometimes, the focus will leave the terminal and will not return until I have closed the file. Other times, the terminal will maintain a prompt, as if I had run:

```
gedit filename.txt &
```

Why this discrepancy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It usually depends on whether `gedit` is already running.

- If it is, the open jibbery gets sent to the open process and depending on how things are running (Gedit 3.x seems to have some weird behaviours) it'll fork into a new window or just a new tab.
- If it's not, a new process is started as a child of the prompt, so it blocks the prompt.

If it really annoys you, you can create an alias, or a `~/bin/` script to override the standard behaviour and force it to fork out with `&` every time.

Comment: Good work, thanks. I hadn't noticed that sometimes I had/didn't have gedit running.

Answer (score 0):

You can force it to open in a new window with the -s parameter:

```
gedit -s filename.txt
```

This will always give it focus.